# Error in Publishing a code in matlab

Tags: matlab

I published the following code in Matlab, although the desired output was produces, but along with that it also generated an error while publishing. Any idea why?

```
%% Gaussian kernel function
% Some text
function t0 = kachra(Param)
t0 = Param;
end
```

Attached is the Published output.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify an input to your function when publishing.

If you select `Edit Publishing Options` you see the following GUI:

[image: yay]

Modify your expression here and then publish it in order for input arguments to be passed.

Comment: Thanks @excaza,for the time beingI changed the Option 'Evaluate Code' to 'False'

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure custom settings to publish your code with output result.

```
[t0] = kachra(100); %the argument is of your choice.
```

[add your command-line input argument manually here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akaa5.png)

Comment: Please provide relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.