# How to publish a code with example

Tags: matlab

I have this function in Matlab:

```
function [L,A]=LU_factor(A,n)    
L=eye(n);
for k=1:n
    if (A(k,k) == 0) Error('Pivoting is needed!'); end
    L(k+1:n,k)=A(k+1:n,k)/A(k,k);
    A(k+1:n,:) = A(k+1:n,:) - L(k+1:n,k)*A(k,:)
end
```

And when I use command line and create matrix `A = rand(4,4)` and compute `[L U] = LU_factor(A,4)` everything is fine and I get the desired result. But when I try to publish it i get this error:

> Error using LU_factor (line 2) Not enough input arguments.

How can I publish my work in a file so it contains both the function and the example. (Sorry I'm completely new to Matlab).

Comment: Completely off-topic - Start accepting solutions on your previous question? It seems you are using them in here.

Comment: @Divakar Sorry I forgot to accept the last question's answer, But why this one is Off-topic? Should I ask it somewhere else?

Comment: I meant my question/comment was off-topic :)

Comment: Personally I'd recommend getting `dput.m` off FileExchange and using that to "publish" the variables.  Much easier for recipients to load the data that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way is to have a main function and then publish:

```
function main
A = rand(4);
n = 2;
[L,A]=LU_factor(A,n)
end

function [L,A]=LU_factor(A,n)    
L=eye(n);
for k=1:n
    if (A(k,k) == 0) 
        error('Pivoting is needed!'); 
    end
    L(k+1:n,k)=A(k+1:n,k)/A(k,k);
    A(k+1:n,:) = A(k+1:n,:) - L(k+1:n,k)*A(k,:)
end
end
```

[image]

The other way has been mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950988/error-in-publishing-a-code-in-matlab) already.